# PSR-4 Autoloader not recognizing classes in subfolder structure

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am using Slim PHP as the underlaying framework for my app and composer autoload for the loading of my classes. In composer i have this psr-4 configuration:

```
 "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/classes/"
    }
```

All my classes are in **/app/classes/** folder.

In my classes folder i have all common classes but module specific classes i have in sub folders.

From my ../classes/connect.php file i am having this method under the corresponding namespace:

```
namespace App;
class connect
{
  public function authenticate(){
    office\AuthenticationManager::acquireAppToken(200);
  }
}
```

In my subfolder ../classes/office/ i have a file called office.php with this method:

```
namespace App\office;
    class AuthenticationManager
    {
        public function acquireAppToken($tid)
        {
           \App\APIManager\RequestManager::sendPostRequest();
        }
    }
```

The above method is calling another method which is located in ../classes/api.php

The namespace in that file is

```
namespace App\APIManager;
```

The problem is that when calling on this last method i get the following error:
"\App\APIManager\RequestManager" not found...

I already tried to solve this with composer dump-autoload, but it did not help. Why is this error happening?

Comment: I would say calling a static function of another class from within a class in separate namespace a bad practice.  It's much better to use dependency injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a class named `RequestManager` in `App\APIManager` namespace, then it must be located in `APIManager/RequestManager.php` file.

It also applies to the `AuthenticationManager` class, which should be moved to `office/AuthenticationManager.php`

Have a look at [PSR-4 examples](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md#3-examples).